# A nice problem about convex functions and minimums.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

We are given a function $f: \mathbb{I} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{I} = ]a,b[$ and $f$ is of the class $C^2.$

We also have:

- $\forall x \in \mathbb{I} : f''(x) \neq 0$.
- $f$ is convex.

Prove that if $f$ has a minimum it is unique. Then prove that $f''$ preserves the same sign over $\mathbb{I}$.

I solved it as follows:

- Proving that if there is a minimum, it must be unique:

We use a proof by contradiction, suppose $f$ accepts to minimums at two points $x$ and $y$ such that $x \neq y$. We know that $f'(x) = 0$ and $f'(y) = 0$.
So by Rolle's theorem there exists a $z$ such that $x \leq z \leq y$ that satifies$f''(z) = 0$. Which is impossible. Hence there can be only one minimum.

- Proving that $f''$ preserves the same sign over $\mathbb{I}$:

$f$ is of class $C^2$, hence $f''(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{I}$. Since $f''(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{I}$, if $f''$ is negative then it stays negative (resp. positive), because by the intermediate value theorem if $f''(c_1) > 0 > f''(c_2)$ there exits a $c_3$ such that $f''(c_3) = 0$, which is not possible.

Are these answers correct? Are there better solutions? :)

Comment: It is correct, but note that the convexity condition is not needed.

Comment: @MartinR Actually there is another question, show that if $f$ admits an extreme point, it must be a minimum. I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: @mmmmh mmmmmh You can show that the derivative of a differentiable convex function must be nondecreasing, and so $\ f''(x)\ge0\ $ if it's twice differentiable, and since you're told  $\ f''(x)\ne0\ $, it must be positive. This is sufficient to imply that any extreme point must be a minimum.